# How to pass bounded wildcard type argument in Kotlin?

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, wicket, wildcard

The class used (in Java, third party API, not changeable):

```
public class BookmarkablePageLink<T> extends Link<T> {

    public <C extends Page> BookmarkablePageLink(final String id, final Class<C> pageClass)
```

And now I want to call this from Kotlin:

```
item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink("link", bookmark.page))
```

`bookmark.page` is in Java, and it is: `public Class<? extends WebPage> getPage()`

None of these work:

```
item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink("link", bookmark.page))
```

> Error: Not enough information to infer parameter **T** in `constructor Bookmarkable PageLink<T : Any!, C : Page!>(...)`

```
item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<>("link", bookmark.page))

item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any>("link", bookmark.page))

item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any, *>("link", bookmark.page))

item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any, WebPage>("link", bookmark.page))

item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any, in WebPage>("link", bookmark.page))

item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any, out WebPage>("link", bookmark.page))

item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any, T : WebPage>("link", bookmark.page))
```

This would be the "hypothetically correct" way to do this in Javaish-speak (just the intention, but it's not real code), but [this isn't supported by Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance):

```
item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any, ? extends WebPage>("link", bookmark.page))
```

My best workaround is this, which is ugly, but works:

```
item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any, WebPage>("link", bookmark.page as Class<WebPage>))
```

Surprisingly in Java this was simply:

```
item.queue(new BookmarkablePageLink<>("link", bookmark.getPage() ));
```

Comment: `<Any, T : WebPage>`

Comment: @Zoe: doesn't work - `Unresolved reference: T` then `Unexpected type specification`

Comment: Hmm... why would someone downvote a question that has no valid answer yet and is not trivially found even after trying to read the official docs? Strange, but that's life..

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match: Java call has 2 type parameters and 3 parameters, declaration has 1 and 2. And what's `getParams` type?

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyRomanov, I've removed the params parameter as it is not relevant to this problem. However regarding the 1 vs 2 type parameter, that is because the class has 1 type parameter and the constructor has 1 type parameter, totalling 2 type parameters, so they actually match.

Comment: I kinda wonder if `public BookmarkablePageLink(final String id, final Class<? extends Page> pageClass)` works

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that's an API I cannot change. Besides, it would defeat the purpose if I have to manipulate Java code in order to call it from Kotlin...

Comment: No, I'm only curious because the template argument doesn't seem necessary based on the snippet. `item.queue<WebPage>(BookmarkablePageLink("link", bookmark.page))` should work.

Comment: There's T and there's C, two type arguments are needed.

Comment: Oh... Now I see it, your constructor has a template argument. In that case I really don't know why it's not just a wildcard like I initially said. Ah well. At least now I know that despite being Wicket 7, its api is a mess

Comment: Java is simpler, as it is less safe ;-).
Kotlin deals with this at compile-time and java during runtime.
Casting is the way to go

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I wholeheartedly disagree that Wicket's API is a mess. Having used Wicket for several years, Wicket did *a lot* of API design right. Use of type parameters in Wicket makes the API very safe, although at rare times the type system gets in the way. Which IMO not the API's fault, but how language treats the type parameters. And we still have the option to "skip" these checks if we're sure what we're doing anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am creating a answer from all the best comments because those already seem very valuable.

Workaround from the question is already a good start:

```
BookmarkablePageLink<Any, WebPage>("link", bookmark.page as Class<WebPage>)
```

Also fair is @AlexeyRomanov's intermediate variable (or a similar intermediate function):

```
val link: BookmarkablePageLink<Any> = BookmarkablePageLink("link", bookmark.page)
```

Also valuable for all who find this question via Google might be a short summary of Kotlin vs Java handling of type-variance as explained in [Kotlin's documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance):

- in Java the handling is at call-site using wildcards (which you can't use, because call-site is in Kotlin)
- and in Kotlin the handling is at declaration site using `in` and `out` keywords (which you can't use, because your declaration is in Java)

Additionally, Java constructors at call-site only allow to specify type arguments from the class, while in Kotlin the constructor call has two type arguments: one from the class and the other from the constructor.
So in Java, we have to say

```
new BookmarkablePageLink<T>("something", Page.class)
```

and in Kotlin

```
BookmarkablePageLink<T, Page>("something", Page::class.java)
```

despite both calling the same constructor with the same arguments.

Given that Kotlin chose an approach for variant types which is the exact opposite of Java's, I am still happy, that we only need workarounds in so few cases. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

So far as I understand, `BookmarkablePageLink(...)` should be approximately equivalent to `new BookmarkablePageLink<>` in Java, so this is the option which "should" work. All others you tried shouldn't, each for different reasons.

Constructors which have their own type parameters are very rare (before seeing this question I thought they were illegal), so they may be overlooked somewhere in Kotlin compiler. A possible workaround is to make it a function instead:

```
fun <T, C : Page> makeBookmarkablePageLink(id: String, clazz: Class<C>): BookmarkablePageLink<T> = 
    BookmarkablePageLink<T, C>(id, clazz)
```

and then

```
item.queue(makeBookmarkablePageLink("link", bookmark.page))
```

I'll also note that I'm pretty sure

> the "correct" way to do this in Java-speak

is actually wrong; and in fact you can't write down the type parameters in Java explicitly, because the second type parameter is a [captured wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10).

Comment: You're right that "the correct way in **Java-speak**" is wrong, because it is **not Java**. I've edited the question to clarify it. The Java way to write it is as I put in the question "Surprisingly in Java this was simply"

Comment: `BookmarkablePageLink(...)` gives me: Error: Not enough information to infer parameter **T** in `constructor Bookmarkable PageLink<T : Any!, C : Page!>(...)`

So, no, Kotlin's missing diamond operator is not equivalent to `<>` in Java. Maybe somewhat similar, but Kotlin's definitely stricter.

Comment: That's why I said "should", not "is".

Comment: Actually, that it fails to infer `T` rather than `C` is useful information; what is the type `item.queue` expects?

Comment: Can you also try `val link: BookmarkablePageLink<Any> = BookmarkablePageLink("link", bookmark.page); item.queue(link)`? This would specify only `T = Any`, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: If that works, then `item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink("link", bookmark.page) as BookmarkablePageLink<Any>)` also might work thanks to http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#information-from-explicit-casts-is-used-for-type-inference.

Comment: item.queue() is irrelevant actually .. you can replace it with someObjectList.add() or even let it go altogether, doesn't matter

Comment: Yup, the `val link` works... But it's not a convenient workaround.

Comment: no, `... as BookmarkablePageLink<Any>` doesn't work, Kotlin still cannot infer T. Probably because it needs to get what the actual type is first before it comes to the "as".

Comment: If you need it once, `val link` seems to be OK to me (though maybe someone will still come up with a better option); if more often, you could define `fun linkForClass(id: String, clazz: Class<out Page>): BookmarkablePageLink<Any> = BookmarkablePageLink(id, clazz)` (modify depending on what will vary in your code).

Comment: Thanks, these are all decent workarounds. Although, this proves that at least in this case, Java's syntax is more compact than Kotlin's.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17061 would remove need for workarounds, but I have no idea if (or when) it'll be implemented. Also raising this issue at https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/ could be useful.

Comment: I would agree with comment "Java's syntax is more compact than Kotlin's" if you add "at the cost of type unsafe". Kotlin made a programmer to choose type parameter, while Java somehow makes decision what programmer wants. It proves with `val link` example work - just take type parameter for class.

And I absolutely agree that type parameter for constructor is very strange.

Comment: "what the actual type is first before it comes to the "as"" Kotlin can sometimes use the type in `as` for inference, I linked the change note about it. This case apparently isn't covered, but it might be worth to report and see if it gets fixed (certainly likely to be faster than KT-17061).

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any, WebPage>("link", bookmark.page))
```

Comment: item.queue() has no type parameters. This definitely won't work.

Comment: That's one the things I tried. It's not working because given `WebPage` type argument doesn't match the actual: `? extends WebPage`

Comment: That's weird. I guess it really is `item.queue(BookmarkablePageLink<Any, WebPage>("link", bookmark.page as Class<WebPage>))` then. :(